# jquery reduce decimal; how to run for multiple input from html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At my work, I need to reduce decimal. The following JavaScript does pretty well to reduce decimal, i.e., two decimal to one,

```
 var mynum = 32.34;
  myNumber = mynum.toFixed(2); // result = 32.3
```

I want to convert several values in the same time from a html form, e.g.,

```
 82.77, 69.30, 43.75, 33.44, 26.88, 26.83, 24.89, 24.88, 24.74, 23.07, 19.31, 17.51.
```

to

```
82.8, 69.3, 44.0, 33.4, 26.8 ......
```

I want to have an HTML form that takes input numbers and upon button click or automatically retrieves the result in the same html page.

Comment: Java: A programming language that runs inside the Java Virtual Machine. JavaScript: A completely different scripting language that runs inside web browsers. jQuery: A JavaScript library that makes working with DOM nodes simpler. Your question contains only JavaScript, no Java or jQuery.

Comment: *"The following Jquery does pretty well..."* That's not jQuery. That's native JavaScript. And it doesn't reduce the decimal to one place.

Answer (score 1):

JS

```
$('#formID').submit(function(){
    $('.decimalMe').val().toFixed(2);
});
```

(sample) HTML

```
<form id="formID">
    <input type="text" class="decimalMe" />
</form>
```

So, give all the input fields you want to work on a class of 'decimalMe' (other class names are available). When the form is submitted (and you can trigger this to happen on another event, the jQuery will run 'toFixed' on all inputs with the given class name...

***Updated working version***

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/moonspace/TA37P/1/

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="decimalMe" name="input1" />
<input type="text" class="decimalMe" name="input2" />

<a id="clickMe">Click me</a>
```

jQuery

```
$('#clickMe').click(function(){
    $('.decimalMe').each(function(){
        $(this).val( ($(this).val() * 1).toFixed(2) );
    });
});
```

Basically, this jQuery:
 - loops through all the instantiations of 'decimalMe'
 - reads the value ($(this).val()
 - multiplies it my 1 to make it a number (there are probably better ways of doing this...)
 - does the 'toFixed()' change
 - pops the changed number back into the field it came from '$(this).val( . . . )

I've used a button and 'click' event simply because I can never get a form submit to work properly in jsFiddle . . .

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work, here is the script; http://jsfiddle.net/kudumi/TA37P/

Comment: See my revised answer, it should be working now . . .

Answer (score 1):

you can create an array of your values and loop your code and write it in an other array:

```
var number_list = [ 82.77, 69.30, 43.75, 33.44, 26.88, 26.83, 24.89, 24.88, 24.74, 23.07, 19.31, 17.51];
var result = [];
for(var k in number_list){
  result.push(number_list[k].toFixed(1));
}

// if u not use IE for dev uncomment the line below for see result in console
//console.log(result);
```

e little example with form with input field
jq

```
$('#myid').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var number_list = eval("["+ $(".numberlist").val() +"]");
    var result = [];
    for(var k in number_list){
      // add new number to result array
      if(typeof number_list[k] == "number") result.push(number_list[k].toFixed(1));
      //append new number to a result list: 1.55 -> 1.6
      $("#result").append("<li>"+number_list[k]+" -> "+number_list[k].toFixed(1)+"</li>");
    }
});
```

html

```
<form id="myid">
   <input class="numberlist" type="text"/>
</form>
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

inside this input write number separated by ",".

like: 1.56,213.32423424,5.234234

Comment: I got error; {"error": "Please use POST request"} here is the script http://jsfiddle.net/kudumi/w7reF/

Comment: are you sure to had included jquery (top-left of the jsfiddle window)? i edito your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w7reF/1/

Comment: it works, but how can I get the result in the format of 82.8, 69.3, 44.0, 33.4, 26.8 .... I also opened a new question[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371150/awk-reduce-decimals-for-a-single-multiple-input-values) to use awk.

Comment: this does the job pretty good, how can I post the values from a html form? that can complete the job, thanks

Comment: also how can I have space between values?

Comment: try this... read comment in javascript code:
http://jsfiddle.net/u3hB8/7/ - !!!!!! sorry in ver.7 there is a syntax error... USE THIS VERSION: http://jsfiddle.net/u3hB8/8/

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = [ 82.77, 69.30, 43.75, 33.44, 26.88, 26.83, 24.89, 24.88, 24.74, 23.07, 19.31, 17.51], y =[];
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
   y.push(x[i].toFixed(2));
}
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle that does it on input fields with a target class in a form

```
//when user clicks submit button
$('#submitform').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('form').find('.toFixed1').each(function(){
        var val = parseFloat($(this).val());
        //only perform operation on an actual number
        if(!isNaN(val)){
            //overwrite the value of the field with the reduced decimal number
            $(this).val(val.toFixed(1));
        }

    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ucu64/1/