# awk reduce decimals for a single multiple input values

Tags: bash, awk

I want to transform the following

```
82.77, 69.30, 43.75, 33.44, 26.88, 26.83, 24.89, 24.88, 24.74, 23.07, 19.31
```

into

```
82.8, 69.3, 44.0, 33.4, 26.8, ...
```

I think `awk` seems to be the easy way to do this. The following does work for a single input value

```
echo 123.45567 | awk '{printf("%.1f\n", $1)}'
```

How can I do this for the above multiple input values with the space delimiter with `awk` or is there any better way to do this? Yesterday I was trying with [java script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351750/jquery-reduce-decimal-how-to-run-for-multiple-input-from-html-page/20351891?noredirect=1#comment30385486_20351891) which didn't work.

Comment: pls explain, why `82.77->82.8` but `43.75->44.0` and `26.88->26.8`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop over each field:

```
$ awk  -F', ' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%.1f%s",$i,(i==NF?RS:FS)}'
```

By setting the field separator to be `,` *(a comma followed by a space)* the input format is preserved in the output. The condition `(i==NF?RS:FS)` checks if we have reached the last field in the record and separates the output accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`, you can loop trough all fields.

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%.1f, ",$i);print ""}' file
82.8, 69.3, 43.8, 33.4, 26.9, 26.8, 24.9, 24.9, 24.7, 23.1, 19.3, 17.5,
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this:

```
s='82.77, 69.30, 43.75, 33.44, 26.88, 26.83, 24.89, 24.88, 24.74, 23.07, 19.31, 17.51.'
awk '{printf("%.1f\n", $1)}' RS=, <<< "$s"
82.8
69.3
43.8
33.4
26.9
26.8
24.9
24.9
24.7
23.1
19.3
17.5
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Q:** how can I do this for the above multiple input values with the space delimiter with awk

**A:** Try setting the *RS* record separator to a space:

```
echo '82.77 69.30 43.75 33.44 26.88 26.83 24.89 24.88 24.74 23.07 19.31 17.51' \ 
| awk 'BEGIN{RS=" "} {printf("%.1f\n", $1)}' 
82.8
69.3
43.8
33.4
26.9
26.8
24.9
24.9
24.7
23.1
19.3
17.5
```